# What does Fortification do?

Tags: mass-effect-3

This power is a bonus power from importing a Soldier from ME2.

The description is as follows:

> Reinforce armor using protective Foucault currents.  Purge the current and send its charge to your gauntlets for increased melee damage.
>
> Slow down power use.

Not entirely sure what this power is doing.  It is an active ability (akin to ammo mods) but it seems when I use Adrenaline Rush, it does not do anything at all.  Melee damage seems to be the same to me as well.

Anyone have a comprehensive idea what this power is actually supposed to be doing and how to effectively use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortification is, [as the wiki describes](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Fortification), an alternative Barrier skill that gives an Armor bonus.

> Fortification reinforces armor with a non-Newtonian fluid that hardens when struck, providing a brief, huge bonus. 
>   Reinforce armor using protective Foucault currents.
>   Purge the current and send its charge to your gauntlets for increase melee damage.
>
> - Slows power usage by 60%.
> - Damage Reduction: 15%
> - Melee Damage Bonus: 50%
> - Melee Damage Duration: 20 sec

You can see the [Power Ranks for Fortification](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Fortification#Power_Ranks_2) at the Wiki too.

Comment: The description from the Wiki compares it quite clearly to the mechanics of two powers from the ME2 version, I suspect it's on the wrong side of the line on the Wiki page. The ME3 version is *quite* different, and the exact mechanics are a bit unclear from reading the power description.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz damage reduction, slows down power cooldown, melee damage bonus, what's not clear about about that? I'll edit in those instead of the descripition, I didn't realize it's probably from ME2

Comment: Well for one thing, Fortification is functionally *very different* from ME3's Barrier, even though the two were interchangable in ME2.

Answer (score 8):

Fortification and Tech Armor are similar powers - both have a 2-stage activation.

When you first activate the power, you gain the defensive bonuses.  This allows you to charge an enemy position.  Once you've gotten into melee range, you can press the button again to (in Fortification's case) channel the power of the defensive bonus into a melee bonus.

The drawback of having the defensive bonus is that your power cooldowns will be increased.  This is to keep you from just leaving the barrier up continuously.

Tech Armor has similar effects, except that unlike Fortification's melee bonus, Tech Armor detonates a small shockwave around you when you set it off instead.

Comment: How does Fortifications detonation/activation interact with the Cooldown on other powers? Which of the two stages triggers it, or do both?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, I believe the first phase is where you've got the cooldown penalties.  I'm more familiar with Tech Armor, which doesn't really *have* a second phase to speak of.

Answer (score -3):

It probably makes it so you don't get hurt as much.