# In mass effect 3, how does Fortification work?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does Fortification do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54386/what-does-fortification-do)

Does fortification increase Damage resistance in general? Or just Health? Or Shield/Barrier?

Comment: very similar question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54386/what-does-fortification-do

Comment: I searched.. Came up with nothing.. =/